# find duplicates in column (DB2, SQL)

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables.

first in a table holding accounts (organizations)

```
ID      IK
1A      1
2X      2
3R      3
4Q      3
5E      5 
6A      5
7B      5
8N      8
9Z      9
```

Every account is part of a grouping called IK and has a IK number. The same number means part of the same IK group. Some accounts are part of a group of 1, like 1A, and some IK groups have multiple members like IK 5 that has 3 accounts as members.

Second table is an extension table to the accounts table. The account ID (org_id) of this table refers to the row_id of the accounts table

```
ID     ORG_ID  KRB_FLG
1U     1A      Y
2O     2X      N
3K     3R      Y
4L     4Q      N
5F     5E      N 
6G     6A      Y
7H     7B      Y
8V     8N      Y
9W     9Z      Y
```

On the extension table, the x_krb_flg indicates the primary (value = "Y") of the IK group. So org 1A is primary of its IK (1). Org 3R is primary of its IK (1-100-10). Each IK group should have at least 1 primary (value "Y" at column X_KRB_FLG) and also a maximum of 1 primary (hence the word primary).

Where I need help with:
I want to find accounts that are in IK groups that do not have a primary, or have more than 1 primary.

I want to find these account records:

- 2X (only member in its IK, but isn't primary)
- 5E (its IK has two primaries)
- 6A (its IK has two primaries)
- 7B (its IK has two primaries)

Comment: It'd be better to give an actual results table, instead of just an explanation (although what you've given is understandable from a records point of view).  What have you tried so far - show the effort you've done, as it'll help us understand your actual needs better.  Which version/platform of DB2?  Do we need to do anything about `ID` in the extension table? (and why are they letters and numbers, anyways?)  Do you have any auditing information, like `made_primary_on` timestamps (most recent value) - Booleans are often derived information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T3 AS (
  SELECT T2.*, T1.IK 
  FROM T1
  INNER JOIN T2
  ON T1.ORG_ID = T2.ORG_ID
  WHERE KRB_FLG = 'Y'
  )
SELECT ORG_ID
FROM T1 AS T
WHERE 1 <> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T3 WHERE T3.IK = T.IK)
;
```

Edit: [Here is a SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b79a9a/2) but syntax was changed for mysql.